# Modify file contents based on Windows' version

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I want to add few lines in a text file based on os name. A pseudocode example:

```
os==windows 7 then open file c:\1.txt else open file c:\2.txt
```

I want to add some  static text to that  text file and save the text file.
How do I do that in batch script? My pseudocode attempt:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %i IN ('ver') DO set osver=%i
echo %osver% 

if %osver% == "Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]"

set filepath == C:\1.txt and open 1.txt file and add text" abc "
else
set filepath == C:\2.txt and open 2.txt file and add text " abc"
```

Comment: Well I can tell you made no effort at learning the syntax for any of those commands. You can read the help file for any command by typing the command name followed by a forward slash and question mark. set /?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not over complicate it by creating variables, else you might need `delayedexpansion`

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%i in ('ver ^| more +1') do (
  if "%%i"=="Version 10.0.17134.228" echo abc >> "C:\1.txt"
  if "%%i"=="Version 6.1.7601" echo abc >> "C:\2.txt"
)
```

We split away `version X.X.X.X` only as we want to match as little as possible. Then simply do if and echo to the relevant file.

For more on the above commands, see from cmdline `for /?` and `if /?`

You need to copy the above code into a text file and save it as a file with a `.cmd` or `.bat` extension. **Please** do not call it `ver.bat` or `ver.cmd` as `ver` is a system command. Call it something like `my_version_script.cmd` instead.

Comment: it works find but my requirement is to add the text to the file not for entire text replacement

Comment: Add what text to the file? You did not specify, but I gave exactly that. Do you want to excho the actual version to the file?

Comment: i have static text which contains two lines , so i have to add these two lines to 1.txt or 2 txt based on os

Comment: So that is what I did... replace lines `echo some text` and `echo some other text` with `echo your static text` your static text

Comment: I edited it with `abc` to show where you should place your static text.

Comment: your code working fine ,but my 1.txt is already contails some text so i have to add the static lines to that file. but the script you mentions is replacing all the contents of the file with the static text.

Comment: @naveen then you did not look at my edit, I added double redirect `>>` Please copy the code and try again.